# remove number from beginning of filename

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed

I have a huge list of the filename as below format.

```
807630007_ sample Authorization (03).pdf
00456007_9760sample Authorization (06).pdf
00259007_9560Customerchoice Authorization (08).pdf
```

I need to extract the filename as below.

```
sample Authorization (03).pdf
sample Authorization (06).pdf
Customerchoice Authorization (08).pdf
```

```
$ echo "00259007_9560Customerchoice Authorization (08).pdf"|sed 's/^1234567890_//'
00259007_9560Customerchoice Authorization (08).pdf
```

Trying to remove numbers and underscores from the beginning of the file. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the prefix containing digits, underscore and the space character, use

```
sed 's/^[0-9_ ]*//'
```

e.g.

```
for i in *.pdf; do
  echo "$i" | sed 's/^[0-9_ ]*//'
done
```

Comment: many thanks, working perfectly. much appreciated your help.